# error: [polling_error] Telegram bot, unhandled error, Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

When sending a user's contact in a telegram bot, an error appears in the console:

```
error: [polling_error] {}
```

The contact is sent, everything works correctly, all other commands work, the error is when sending the user's contact.

```
bot.telegramBot.on("message", (msg) => {
const { id } = msg.chat; // decomposition
const { first_name } = msg.from; // decomposition

switch (msg.text.toLocaleLowerCase()) {
  case "/start":
    bot.telegramBot.sendMessage(
      id,
      `${first_name}, Вас приветствует Телеграм Бот - MyClub! Для авторизации необходимо отправить свой номер телефона.`,
      {
        reply_markup: {
          keyboard: [
            [
              {
                text: "Отправить",
                request_contact: true,
              },
            ],
          ],
        },
      }
    );
    break;
});
```

I googled that this error is unhandled + a syntax error is possible, but I can’t understand what the problem is in this case. I will be glad for any help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think it goes more to the syntax of the /start command, since I tried to put certain restrictions on its use (such as checking if it is registered in my database), and I still got a "polling error" even though all the other commands worked.

I think it's something from the Telegram API, because remember that every BOT starts with /start, and if that command is manipulated it can cause certain errors.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).